# If the Quran is such a miracle, then why do so many Arabs still reject Islam today?

Tags: quran, arabic, miracles

We know that even during the Prophet's (pbuh) days, many Arabs did not believe that he was a prophet. And even today, there are many christian arabs who don't believe that the Quran is a miracle. There are even some christian arabs who believe that the Quran is a miracle, yet they don't believe in Islam. Why is that?

If the Quran was such a linguistic miracle, wouldn't all Arabs be muslims right now? I mean, who would be able to comprehend the miracle of the Quran better than the Arabs?

In Surah Bayyinah, Allah describes Muhammad (pbuh) and the Quran as "Bayyinah", which means "the clear evidence". If Muhammad (pbuh) and the Quran are such a clear evidence, why do so many Arabs still reject it? (I might start another topic about the meaning of Bayyinah)

Comment: for modern arabs the majority of them are not good in arabic , but this is not the main  reseon !

Comment: They reject it because they didn't witness it. You must be aware that our Prophet has considered as more than his sahaba because we believed in him without seeing witnessing him.

Comment: The Prophet was not  sent to the Arabs only but to mankind. The Qur'an is a guidance for mankind even though written in Arabic.  Anybody who has an open heart can be guided even by a translation of  the Qur'an. There will be always people who reject the truth even though it might be standing  directly infront of their own eyes.

Comment: @Noor Rejecting of truth comes mostly from ideological bias. The most clear-cut and widespread cases of people rejecting truth nowadays are people rejecting evolution, or that the earth is billions of years old. I don't think it's a good strategy for religious people to say that people will reject truth even when it is crystal clear in support of their religion, but I do realize that the Quran gives incentive to say it.

Comment: I don't see how this could be answered objectively. You really should ask non-Muslim Arabs this question; others can only speculate on the reason(s) why they reject it

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of reasons of kufr (disbelief) and does not always depend on miracles. Likewise, there are a lot of reasons for belief, not always involving miracles.  One of the main reasons is al-fitra (natural disposition).

> [فِطْرَةَ اللَّهِ الَّتِي فَطَرَ النَّاسَ عَلَيْهَا](https://quran.com/30/30)

Today we have 1.5 billion Muslims that didn't see miracles that had been seen by sahaba and quraich people, and they are believers.  We have thousands of new Muslims every year, which didn't know a lot about the Quran. And they don't know Arabic like quraich the people.

And you said that there are even some Christian Arabs who believe that the Quran is a miracle, yet they don't believe in Islam.  That means there are reasons that make them reject Islam.

**Why do Arabs who have received a very clear message reject it?**

As said above, there are a lot of reasons people reject these messages, some of this are in Islamic stories and ahadith and narrations, and some others in the Quran, and some in both.  To avoid translation narrations and find them, I will count some reasons that had been mentioned in Quran.

- Ingratitude and obstinacy: Denial the truth even after know it.

  > وَجَحَدُوا بِهَا وَاسْتَيْقَنَتْهَا أَنْفُسُهُمْ ظُلْمًا وَعُلُوًّا
  >
  > And they rejected them, while their [inner] selves were convinced
  >   thereof, out of injustice and haughtiness
  >
  > [Quran 27/14](https://quran.com/27/14)
- Pride and arrogance: and the example of Satan is very clear.

  > وَإِذْ قُلْنَا لِلْمَلائِكَةِ اسْجُدُوا لِآدَمَ فَسَجَدُوا إِلاَّ
  >   إِبْلِيسَ أَبَى وَاسْتَكْبَرَ وَكَانَ مِنَ الكَافِرِينَ
  >
  > And [mention] when We said to the angels, "Prostrate before Adam"; so
  >   they prostrated, except for Iblees. He refused and was arrogant and
  >   became of the disbelievers
  >
  > [Quran 2:34](https://quran.com/2/34)
- Intolerance towards parents and grandparents:

  > وَإِذَا قِيلَ لَهُمُ اتَّبعُوا مَا أَنزَلَ اللّهُ قَالُواْ بَلْ
  >   نَتَّبِعُ مَا أَلْفَيْنَا عَلَيْهِ آبَاءنَا أَوَلَوْ كَانَ آبَاؤُهُمْ
  >   لاَ يَعْقِلُونَ شَيْئاً وَلاَ يَهْتَدُونَ
  >
  > And
  >   when it is said to them, "Follow what Allah has revealed," they say,
  >   "Rather, we will follow that which we found our fathers doing." Even
  >   though their fathers understood nothing, nor were they guided?
  >
  > [Quran 2:170](https://quran.com/2/170)
- Envy and jealousy:

  > وَدَّ كَثِيرٌ مِنْ أَهْلِ الْكِتَابِ لَوْ يَرُدُّونَكُمْ مِنْ بَعْدِ
  >   إِيمَانِكُمْ كُفَّاراً حَسَداً مِنْ عِنْدِ أَنْفُسِهِمْ مِنْ بَعْدِ
  >   مَا تَبَيَّنَ لَهُمُ الْحَقُّ
  >
  > Many of the People of the Scripture wish they could turn you back to
  >   disbelief after you have believed, out of envy from themselves [even]
  >   after the truth has become clear to them
  >
  > [Quran 2:109](https://quran.com/2/109)
- Prophet accused of being a magician:

  > وَإِن يَرَوْا آيَةً يُعْرِضُوا وَيَقُولُوا سِحْرٌ مُّسْتَمِرٌّ
  >
  > And if they see a miracle, they turn away and say, "Passing magic."
  >
  > [Quran 54:2](https://quran.com/54/2)

Comment: One thing I don't understand though: How can you blame the people who thought that the prophet was a magician? I think it's very understandable for any miracle to be mistaken for magic. It's a bit unfair if you think about it. When the prophet performed a miracle, the Arabs thought it was magic and Allah hates them. When a christian priests performs a miracle with the so-called holy spirit to prove christianity, we're supposed to pass it off as magic and Allah loves us.

Comment: @curiosity  when jesus , moses and prophets performs a miracle we called a miracle ! when some people like christian priests  and muslim suffis ( a lack of them ) and some other muslims performs a miracle we said this is magic :) ! and you've to know that some Paranormal
 could happend to some people ( believer or not ) .!
they are all eqaul my friend !

Comment: So you're saying non-muslims can perform miracles?

Comment: @curiosity in which part ?

Comment: I have an impulse to downvote this answer because it does not reflect the actual reasons Non-Muslims really have for rejecting Islam. but it does reflect what Islam says why they reject it.

Comment: @G.Bach well it's islam SE ! what islam say is  totally accepted !

Comment: But the question asks why they _actually_ reject it, not what Islam says the reasons are. Maybe you could improve your answer by also doing some research about that?

Comment: @TheRavenQueen yes